# undefined reference to _mm_crc32_u64

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

I have a program that uses `_mm_crc32_u64`. I include the header file `smmintrin.h` for that purpose and also use the flag `-msse4.1` when compiling it with `gcc`. However, when I compile it I get `undefined reference to _mm_crc32_u64` error. What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you post the full gcc command you use to build?

Comment: hmjd: gcc -msse4.1 crc.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it like this and it worked! So basically I had to use msse4.2 instead of msse4.1.

```
gcc44 crc.c -msse4.2
```